Performing arithmetic on tensors yields different results than arithmetic on values in tensors
I've got some code that performs arithmetic operations on tensors in Pytorch. Here's one of the equations I'm using:
tau = self.Cm / self.gl
V_new = V_old + (self.dt/tau)*(-1 * V_old + I/self.gl)

Cm and gl are constants (doubles), V_old is a 64x500 double tensor, and I is a 64x500 float tensor. The issue I'm having is that the values in the created tensor, V_new, are wrong.
In other words, if I pick any random index (I've been using [37, 345] as my test), performing the above operation using the values of V_old[37, 345] (double) and I[37, 345] (float) yields a different number than V_new[37, 345].
Computing using values:-67.97208919525147
Value stored in tensor: -67.97208923339844
While this issue seems trivial, the code later does more arithmetic using V_new, whose erroneous result is then used for more arithmetic, etc. So the error propagates to problematic levels very quickly.
Can anyone help me understand why this is happening, and how I can make the values in the tensor more accurate?

A 32-bit float is only good for about 7 decimal digits of precision, so those results seem about the best you can hope for.  Keeping everything as 64-bit doubles would be the obvious thing to try.

Thank you! Turns out I didn't understand how floats in Python work (I assumed they were 32 bits)
